# WatchKit app is not launching in Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, watchkit, watchos-simulator

I'm integrating watchkit in my existing iOS project.So I created watchkit target and added one label in WatchKit's Interface.Storyboard file(Watch OS-2.2 ,Xcode- 8.0,iPhone 6s-ios10).But when Im running this app its not launching in watch simulator and also nothing is happening in iphone 6S.Is there any additional configuration need to do for watchkit app to make it running? On Watch simulator currently it is showing default screen i.e.Analog clock.

Comment: did u select watch simulator while running?

Comment: @SathiReddy -Yes I have selected that simulator.That device selection option is as " iPhone 6s +Apple watch 38mm ".

Comment: Resolved.Just go to home in WatchKit simulator and tap on App icon.It will run.